# Getting position of dynamically created Imageviews and applying onTouchListener on them

Tags: android, dynamic, imageview

I have created Image views Dynamically in a horizontal scroll view. XML and Java Code is below.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsv"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/hsvll">


                  </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Java Code**

```
FileInputStream fin = null;
        int length = arrayList.size();
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            ImageView image = new ImageView(getContext());
            image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(250,250));
            image.setMaxHeight(60);
            image.setMaxWidth(60);
            try {
                fin = openFileInput(arrayList.get(i).getImage());
                if(fin !=null && fin.available() > 0) {
                    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fin);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    layout.addView(image);
                } else {
                    //input stream has not much data to convert into  Bitmap
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
```

**NOTE:** As u can see my code i am getting references of images from an arraylist and my images are being saved in some directory.

Here are my Questions:
**1)** How can i get the positions of these images created dynamically.
**2)** How can i apply the onclick or **onTouchListener** on these created images.

Comment: what positions are you talking about? View#getLeft(), View#getTop(), View#getX(), View#getY() ? also what  problems do you have with OnTouchListener ?

Comment: how to apply? what do you mean? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: Well i can see a list of these images in my horizontal list view you can say i simply want to show  a toast that "This image is clicked".

Comment: then use `View#setOnClickListener`

Comment: oky But is it possible if u can show me a bit detailed sample code as i am totally new to android.

Comment: just call it, nothing else is required for it to work

Comment: Thnx for help this discussion Helped me a lot :)